# Pandas panelnd vs dataframe with hierarchical index

Tags: pandas

I was wondering when and why I should prefer a panel(nd) over a dataframe with hierarchical index, and vice versa. In my very brief experience, I would say that the former is more convenient for slicing, while the latter for mathematical operations. My particular need would be to interactively manipulate 3-5 dimensional panels with convenient slicing and element-wise operations.

Thanks,

Giacomo

Answer (score 1):

Generally stick with a multi-indexed frame as they are more fully supported.

A `panelnd` is like a generalized n-dim Panel, good mainly for single-dtyped data. It does work like a Panel, but has some quirks and missing features (its why its experimental).

Their *are* ways to apply some operations to multiple slabs of a n-dim (esp. via new `apply` in 0.13.1, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-with-a-panel).

Once I get to more than 3 dimensions, I mainly 'hold' the data and slice to work it in 2 dimensions, then reassemble it if needed. Storage can also be convient for these higher dim objects (e.g. via `HDFStore`), and was the reason they were created in the first place.