# How to create an index on a ndarray using pandas

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I'm really intrigued by the indexing of axis provided by pandas. I've worked with numpy lately and have an array, that keeps the position (XYZ) for a number of Particles (1 ... N) for a number of times (0.0 ... T). So that would be a three dimensional (T,N,3) array.

```
D = random((10,20,3))
```

now I'd like to add the pandas indexing to the appropriate axis to make it easier to access certain time frames, or certain selection of atoms. Let's say I'd like to attach the following index labels to the data:

```
T_index = arange( 10, dtype='f' )
N_index = arange( 20 )
P_index = ["x","y","z"]
```

I've looked around but have not found a good way of adding those to a pandas dataframe in a convinient way. I'm also not quite sure if the pandas dataframe is really the data structure I should be using, because maybe it brakes up the originally nicely formed numpy ndarray into something where the convenient numpy functions like mean() or sum() would be much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 3 axes, defining a Panel might be most convenient:

```
pan = pd.Panel(D, items=T_index, major_axis=N_index, minor_axis=P_index)
# <class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
# Dimensions: 10 (items) x 20 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
# Items axis: 0.0 to 9.0
# Major_axis axis: 0 to 19
# Minor_axis axis: x to z
```

Then, if you wish to convert that to a DataFrame, use:

```
df = pan.to_frame()
```

The underlying data in `pan` is still in one numpy array of shape (10, 20, 3):

```
In [50]: pan._data
BlockManager
...
FloatBlock: [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], 10 x 20 x 3, dtype: float64
```

So I wouldn't expect there to be any significant deterioration in speed. And you could always drop back to numpy operations on the numpy array `pan.values` if need be, though, hopefully, that would be unnecessary.

Comment: Would it be better to use the Panel then instead of the Datadrame? Could you briefly expand on the difference?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the data, though there is [more code support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22591833/190597) for multi-level DataFrames.